# Minimizing Code and Getting Same Output

Tags: c

Is there a way to shorten this code? I mean instead of writing so many lines; I could be able to write few lines and get the same output?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int input;
    printf("Enter Input \n");
    scanf("%d",&input);

   switch(input)
    {
        case 1: 
            printf("a");
            break;
        case 2: 
            printf("b");
            break;
        case 3: 
            printf("c");
            break;
        case 4: 
            printf("d");
            break;
        case 5: 
            printf("e");
            break;
        case 6: 
            printf("f");
            break;
        case 7: 
            printf("g");
            break;
        case 8: 
            printf("h");
            break;
        case 9: 
            printf("i");
            break;
        case 10: 
            printf("j");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid Input");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why?  It's already written, and it presumably works.

Comment: I just tried to squeeze it via Nested Cases but that wouldn't help much

Comment: @Baldrick Can you please elaborate a bit

Comment: Compact version: `scanf("%d",&input); putchar( input<: "abcdefghij" -!!- input:>  );`. Most importantly: it works with EBCDIC.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if you're looking for an alternative, you can use an array. Something like

```
 char arr [ ] = "abcdefghij";
```

and then, you can do soemthing like

```
if ( input >= 1 && input <= 10)
    printf("%c", arr[input -1]);
else
    puts ("Invalid");
```

Comment: This has the advantage of working on platforms with non-contiguous character sets (like EBCDIC).

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the way not needing extra storage i.e. an array. ASCII is a prerequisite for the answer. ASCII value of lower-case `a` is 97.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int input;
    printf("Enter Input \n");
    scanf("%2d",&input);

    if (input <= 10 && input >= 1) {
        printf("%c", 'a' + input - 1);
    } else {
        printf("Invalid Input");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I dont get it. Good answer. Id do it the same way

Comment: I am okay with using assumptions such as that the C implementation uses ASCII **provided you state the assumptions**. This answer assumes ASCII (and does mention ASCII) but neither acknowledges that C implementations may use character sets other than ASCII nor explicitly states that ASCII is a prerequisite for this answer to be correct. A part of engineering is stating the requirements. Additionally, the hard-coded `96` is not needed. It would be preferable to use `'a'-1`, as the code could then work for any character set in which a through j are consecutive, not just ASCII.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Sir, I'm young, still studying, a candidate of engineering. So, I've not had yet brilliant experience as yours.   I'll make a mental note of _A part of engineering is stating the requirements._ from now on.   Thank you for the prominent viewpoint.

Answer (score -3):

You can check if `input` is between 1 and 10
If no, print your invalid statement
If yes, print `'a' + ( input - 1 )`

Comment: he implies usage of math to calculate the letter. You utilize char to integer casts to convert between letters and their ASCII values

Comment: *print `'a' + ( input - 1 )`*  No.  Per [the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1) only the digits `'0'`-`'9'` are guaranteed to be represented consecutively.

Comment: @Noi Punghu Isaac Carol Weisberg is true, my goal is to use the ascii value of the letter 'a', and add the value of `input - 1` to increase the ascii value of the letter printed

Comment: @AndrewHenle Am I right that this is the actual reason? Otherwise I don't see a problem with this solution (type conversion might clear up things). If consecutiveness was guaranteed, that would work, wouldn't it? It'd be nice if downvoters would actually explain, like you did.

Comment: @CimCim: Not all platforms use ASCII. This isn't a portable solution, as the behaviour you're relying on is not guaranteed by the standard. (In reality this would work *almost* anywhere - but that's not the point! :) )

Comment: Everyone, on an ASCII-guaranteed platform this would've worked.

Comment: @Andrew Henle I didn't know this rule of character set, I usually consider/use ascii values in which `'b'` is `'a'+1`. For my knowledge, is there some systems on which this will be wrong ? Or is your remark apply for non-ascii charcater set ?

Comment: @Baldrick ok, thank you, you answer the question I was asking myself since I saw the comment of Andrew

Comment: @Baldrick for general knowledge, can you name us one such platform that doesn't use ASCII, even historical?

Comment: @IsaacCarolWeisberg: Mostly mainframes. e.g. IBM System/3, Fujitsu-Siemens' BS2000/OSD. And they are still in fairly widespread use.

Comment: Having the program breaking if executed on an EBCDIC computer is not necessarily a bad thing though. Pedantic people can add `_Static_assert('Z'-'A' == 25, "Crap/EBCDIC not supported.");` on top of their program, then do arithmetic on the character set.

Comment: @Lundin: Perhaps, but it's better to only make assumptions in code that adhere to the standard - and it's not that hard to get this one right! :) But your comment did make me laugh.